# What is the part name and use for this small piece shaped like a lever?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

Looking for part name and use, stamped and has different numbers on each one I find. Small and shaped like a lever. Same size as antenna piece actually.  I feel it is part of a larger piece similar to the [antenna and base part](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4592c02#T=C).

Part numbers on each piece I have found thus far are like 27, 28, 29 with the numbers 01 underneath each one. It's in dark grey and has white marks where they broke it off the part holder bit. Any help would be lovely.

Sorry for photo quality, it's very tiny.

[image: small lego part in grey]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE.  The picture is pretty good, so don't worry about that.  A picture that has a LEGO piece in it for scale would be better, though, if you have a minute.  Are you sure this is LEGO?  Did it come with a bunch of other stuff that was 100% LEGO?

Comment: When you say "Same size as antenna piece" what piece do you mean? Because, as has been answered, it **is** an antenna piece.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of you answering! sorry it took so long to get back to you all. Current events made working difficult this month and I was away from the pc. Thank you for answering with the link of what this lego is! Thats exactly it Alex and Joost! Thank you for fixing my post for legibility Chicks!
RSchulz, The other lego piece I was refer to in my post for size comparison was Antenna Small Base with Black Lever Item No: 4592c02. https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4592c02#T=C I should have linked, my bad.

Answer (score 10):

This is part of [FIGURE ACCESSORIES](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6004908)

[image]

and is used as antenna for the Boba Fett and other mandalorian minifigs

[image]
(Picture from Set 75312)

Comment: It is called [Minifigure, Helmet Antenna / Rangefinder for Helmet SW Clone Trooper with Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61190d) on Bricklink